# How to connect to other Mysql Server

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I am new to mysql and trying to use another computer to connect the database, hope someone will help me.

One computer granted a user name'asb' with a passsword '123'

and went I trid to connect it on another company by using -h 192.168.**.* -u asb -p123;
it doesn't work

anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled remote login for 'asb' user.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL ON database.* TO 'asb'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

If connection still fails, check bind-address and skip-networking options in /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf files.

bind-address option is IP address to bind to.

Comment skip-networking option.

```
#skip-networking
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/1008424) for more info: